# After ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush enabled UI doesn't update

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic5

According to translation change:

```
     setTranslation(): void {
        this.translateService.stream(['Client.Dashboard', 'Client.Active-
Orders']).subscribe(res => {

          const sideMenu: SideMenuModel = {
            dashboard: res['Client.Dashboard'],
            activeOrders: res['Client.Active-Orders'],

          };

          this.setSideMenu(sideMenu); // here it calls
        });
      }
```

I hope this is due to immutability issue here. i.e. `this.sideMenu`. Could you give me any hint here?

```
setSideMenu(sideMenu: SideMenuModel): void {

    this.sideMenu = [
      {
        title: sideMenu.dashboard,
        url: '/dashboard',

      },
      {
        title: sideMenu.activeOrders,
        url: '/active-orders',

      },
]
```

I have enabled `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,`. After that, UI doesn't update properly.

**Note:** I have removed unwanted template code here.

```
 <ion-menu-toggle auto-hide="false" *ngFor="let s of sideMenu; let i = index">

    <ion-item (click)="selectedIndex = i" routerDirection="root" [routerLink]="[s.url]">

    </ion-item>

  </ion-menu-toggle>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my question this is a problem with data mutation. So I have used `BehaviorSubject` with `async` pipe. Now it is working fine without any hacks.

Great article about that: https://blog.angular-university.io/onpush-change-detection-how-it-works/

*html*

```
<ion-menu-toggle *ngFor="let s of sideMenuChanged$ |async; let i = index">


  </ion-menu-toggle>
```

*.ts*

```
  private sideMenuSubject$: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
  sideMenuChanged$: Observable<any> = this.sideMenuSubject$.asObservable();

  constructor(private translateService: TranslateService, ) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.setTranslation();
}

 setTranslation(): void {
    this.translateService.stream(['Client.Dashboard', 'Client.Active-Orders']).subscribe(res => {

      const sideMenu: SideMenuModel = {
        dashboard: res['Client.Dashboard'],
        activeOrders: res['Client.Active-Orders'],
       };

      this.setSideMenu(sideMenu);
    });
  }

setSideMenu(sideMenu: SideMenuModel): void {

    this.sideMenu = [
      {
        title: sideMenu.dashboard,
        url: '/dashboard',
        src: '../assets/images/client/dashboard-side-menu.png'
      },
      {
        title: sideMenu.activeOrders,
        url: '/active-orders',
        src: '../assets/images/common/active-orders.png',
        isActiveOrder: true
      },
     ];

    this.sideMenuSubject$.next(this.sideMenu);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

With OnPush strategy, you need to tell your component to update outside event / @Input(), such as observable subscription:

```js
     constructor(private readonly cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
     setTranslation(): void {
        this.translateService.stream(['Client.Dashboard', 'Client.Active-
Orders']).subscribe(res => {

          const sideMenu: SideMenuModel = {
            dashboard: res['Client.Dashboard'],
            activeOrders: res['Client.Active-Orders'],

          };

          this.setSideMenu(sideMenu); // here it calls
          this.cdRef.markForCheck(); // Tell Angular to run detectChanges on this component
        });
      }
```

Comment: Yes, now it works. Could you give more info about this use case? Which one is better? i.e. should I use default behavior without `OnPush` or use your method with `OnPush`. This is a side menu component. Which one has better performance for the app?

Comment: Is this not due to the mutability issue on `this.sideMenu`?

Comment: Not at all, with OnPush, sideMenu should be a different reference, like you did: `this.sideMenu = ...`. It won't work if you mutate the state of sideMenu like: `this.sideMenu.push(...)`. There should be many blogs talking about how OnPush works. I don't think I can explain better. OnPush will have better performance because the detection change will be run less often, the trade-off is that you need to write more code, and you may forget about it: you should always use immutability for property, and use `ChangeDetectorRef.markForCheck()` with `Observable`

Comment: As I mentioned this is a problem with data mutation. So I have used `BehaviorSubject` with `async` pipe. Now it is working fine without any hacks. Your solution is fine if I use a 3rd party library like Google map Javascript API and etc. But my use case where I work under the Angular Zone. i.e. no need  `ChangeDetectorRef`. Thanks for your feedback too.

Comment: Calling `markForCheck()` is not a hack. Using `BehaviorSubject` with async Pipe make your code even more complex, async Pipe just calls `markForCheck()` underly. I even consider it as bad because you are now having two sources for sideMenu value ...

Comment: I hope you'll read this article. We need to maintain a clean observable based reactive architecture pattern always. https://blog.angular-university.io/onpush-change-detection-how-it-works/

Comment: Yes, he has never mentioned about your method in that article. He is one of the top Angular architect currently we have. I have followed lot of his courses on Udemy too. I extremely believe `pipe` is the very clean solution due to many reasons. e.g. No need manual unsubscribe and etc.